# Using Compass sprites, generated CSS uses all class names as well as shared one

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass, sprite

Say I have some HTML like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html lang="en-US">
  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title></title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css"></link>
  </head>
  <body>
      This is a test
      <a class="ribbons-sprite ribbons-exclusive" href="#">Exclusive</a>
      <a class="ribbons-sprite ribbons-featured" href="#">Featured</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

and I have some SASS (SCSS) like this:

```
@import "compass/utilities"; 
@import "ribbons/*.png";

@include all-ribbons-sprites(true);  

.ribbons-sprite {
   display: inline-block;
   text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

the outputted CSS is this:

```
.ribbons-sprite, .ribbons-exclusive, .ribbons-featured {
  background: url('../images/ribbons-scfb85024fb.png') no-repeat;
}

.ribbons-exclusive {
  background-position: 0 -38px;
  height: 59px;
  width: 59px;
}

.ribbons-featured {
  background-position: 0 0;
  height: 38px;
  width: 70px;
}

.ribbons-sprite, .ribbons-exclusive, .ribbons-featured {
  display: inline-block;
  text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

Why does the last selector list include all classes, not just '.ribbons-sprite'? I can see if I had more items in the sprite it would get unnecessarily bloated. This only seems to be the case when I am using the sprite generator. If I remove this line, the inline block and text indent lines are just under the shared class name selector. Here is what I expected as CSS output:

```
.ribbons-sprite {
  background: url('../images/ribbons-scfb85024fb.png') no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  text-indent: -9999px;
}

.ribbons-exclusive {
  background-position: 0 -38px;
  height: 59px;
  width: 59px;
}

.ribbons-featured {
  background-position: 0 0;
  height: 38px;
  width: 70px;
}
```

Comment: Could you please update it with, what is inside of this "@include all-ribbons-sprites"

Comment: If I were to guess, I would say it is probably legacy code from before they added extend classes.  You aren't really meant to use the `.ribbons-sprite` class on its own.

Comment: Thanks cimmanon. Yes, it seems if I change .ribbons-sprite to .ribbons for example, then it just uses this class for the inline block and text-indent properties. But would rather it use a single class name, than a selector with all three in to define the background image.